# Extends a template which contains the navigation block in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.3, twig-extension

I have a problem with a menu in symfony2. I have a class which loads the content for the first page including the menu :

```
public function indexAction(){
    $aMenu                          = Navigation::buildMenu();
    return $this->render('ShopDesktopBundle::layout.html.twig', array(
            'aProducts' => $aProducts,
            'aMenu'     => $aMenu
        ));
}
```

Now I create a new controller :

```
class CategoryController extends Controller{
public function showCategoryAction($id){
    return $this->render('ShopDesktopBundle:Category:category.html.twig');
 }
}
```

I extends the template : layout.html.twig

```
{% extends 'ShopDesktopBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
```

I get the error :

```
Variable "aMenu" does not exist in ShopDesktopBundle::layout.html.twig at line 89
```

Any idea what might be going wrong? Do I need to create a new template which contains only the navigation block?

Answer (score 3):

First, create `navigation` as a service, then change your configuration:

```
twig:
    globals:
        navigation: "@service_name"
```

You can access it in all your templates by:

```
{{ navigation.buildMenu() }}
```

This doesn't work with static methods. For static methods you can create a twig extension.

For more information read the symfony cookbook on [twig extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem by create a new method in controller :

```
public function menuAction(){
    $aMenu                          = Navigation::buildMenu();
    return $this->render('ShopDesktopBundle:Category:menu.html.twig', array(
        'aMenu'     => $aMenu
    ));
}
```

I created a new view call : menu.html.twig

And in layout.html.twig in block navigation I add :

```
{% block navigation %}
   {{ render(controller( 'ShopDesktopBundle:Home:menu' )) }}
{% endblock %}
```